# aws load balancer times out on simple kubernetes setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a simple 3 node k8s setup. 1 master and 2 workers. The only pods deployed are sample nginx pods.

I am trying to connect an aws loadbalancer to my cluster, but the request keeps timing out.

My k8s loadbalancer looks like this

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
  labels:
    app: nginx
    svc: test-nginx
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 31000
```

when i visit the public ip address of the EC2 node with port 31000, I get the expected "Welcome to nginx!" response, but setting up a loadbalancer via aws with the 2 worker nodes as targets doesn't seem resolve.

any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: The k8s control plane (or aws-load-balancer-controller) is supossed to provision the ELB. It's not something you should need to touch manually. Check your k8s events and/or aws-load-balancer-controller logs

Comment: ah maybe because i'm trying to manually set up a cluster with EC2s (was working through a k8s admin tutorial)